# clojure/lein: How do I include a java file in my project?

Tags: java, import, clojure

I have a java file with a single class and I want to include it in my lein project.  Where do I put it and how do I import it?  (I tried putting it in the src directory under the package path but it tells me ClassNotFound)

So the java file has this package declaration:

```
package com.thebuzzmedia.imgscalr;
```

and has this class:

```
public class Scalr {
```

I put it in ~/src/com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr/Scalr.java
and tried to import it from the repl thusly:

```
(import '(com.thebuzzmedia.imgscalr Scalr))
```

And I get this:

```
com.thebuzzmedia.imgscalr.Scalr
[Thrown class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java and Clojure with Leiningen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432163/java-and-clojure-with-leiningen)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Where to place Java sources really depends on which build system you're using. If you're using Leiningen, [you have to configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432163/java-and-clojure-with-leiningen) the source paths:

```
(defproject my-project "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  [...]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java" "test/java"])
```

Then you can import Java classes at those source locations in your code or at the REPL like you were already trying to do.

Comment: Although I use [cake](http://clojure-cake.org/) and thus don't have to worry about this, my understanding is that newer versions of Lein have javac functionality baked in, without plugins.

Comment: Indeed leiningen merged `javac-plugin` into its main codebase, it's not really a plugin anymore. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date.  Lein now uses :java-source paths as described by kiko and benkay.

Answer (score 13):

As of Leiningen 2.X, `:java-source-path` has been replaced with `:java-source-paths`, whose value is now specified as a vector rather than a string.

Example:

```
(defproject my-project "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  [...]
  :java-source-paths ["src/main/java" "src/main/test"]
  ...)
```

Answer (score 8):

Since I do not have the reputation to comment on the above answers, I am left with no recourse but to leave my own, ever-so-slightly different answer.

The correct syntax (as of Leiningen 2.1.3) is:

```
(defproject
    ...
    :java-source-paths ["src/main/java/" "foo/bar/baz/"]
    ...
)
```