# How do I recompile and reload Java source code while `lein repl` is running?

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I have a Clojure project, and I'm using leiningen. I'm also using tools.namespace to reload Clojure code while running a REPL. If I want to include Java source in the project, can I recompile and reload it while the REPL is running? What is the most convenient/dynamic way of doing it? Can I do it so that it works well with tools.namespace?

Comment: Maybe add `:aot :all` in `project.clj`?

Comment: @halfelf that does not sound like what I want.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing. It'll be a huge win if this functionality is implemented. There is a javac function in https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/cd22728f21132fe986a614205ef5fd18beea91dd/src/leiningen/javac.clj that is included in leiningen

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432163/java-and-clojure-with-leiningen help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering my own bounty here but I did do a bit of work getting this up:

*Use [Vinyasa](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa)*,

and here is a blog post:

[Dynamic reloading of java code in emacs/nrepl](http://z.caudate.me/dynamic-reloading-of-java-code-in-emacsnrepl/)

... actually... it's kinda not working anymore... you have to do back to the earlier versions in order to get the support.

Comment: This library has been completely removed, as well as it's replacement, Lucidity.

Comment: It's still on clojars ... just very much unsupported. virgil's definitely the better option right now.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays (2016->) the better answer is to use [Virgil](https://github.com/ztellman/virgil). It watches and recompiles all Java code in your leiningen project automatically in the background, as opposed to Vinyasa's approach of invoking reimport.

Comment: You don't get nearly enough credit for this, this is definitely the correct answer now :)

Answer (score 3):

Spring-loaded or JRebel might be what you want. Have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/Spring-loaded or http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/. They both provide an agent monitoring the filesystem for class file changes and update class definitions in the running JVM. I personally use Spring-loaded, but not yet together with tools.namespace. I guess the key to run them both is to make sure they do not conflict. So if you use Spring-loaded, it should be the only tool tracking class files and you better not use aot at all. If I remember correctly, tools.namespace discourages the use of aot anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Pure java way

```
public class MyClassFactory {
   public static MyClass newInstance() {
       URLClassLoader cl =
           new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {getMyClassPath()}) {

           public Class loadClass(String name) {
              if ("MyClass".equals(name))
                 return findClass(name);
              return super.loadClass(name);
          }
       };

     return (MyClass) cl.loadClass("MyClass").newInstance();
  }
}
```

by this way you can lead the class loader to load classes programmatically.

**References**

- [Classloader Official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html)
- [Java Specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)
- [OnJava](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

See also the official JVM services loader

[ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)