# mixing java and clojure files in a single package

Tags: java, clojure, interop, leiningen

I'm having troubles compiling a mixture of clojure and java files into a single package. The files have dependencies between each other and if they were all just java files the java compiler could handle all of this. Just to make this concrete I want to create a package called pkg with 4 files, A.java, b.clj, c.clj, and D.java. A.java contains main and creates an object declared in b.clj, b.clj calls functions in c.clj and uses objects of class D. How do I write the project file?

If I use

```
 :prep-tasks ["javac" "compile"]
```

in the project file then I get a complaint while compiling A.java that something in pkg.b or pkg.c is undefined. If I use

```
 :prep-tasks ["compile" "javac"]
```

I get a complaint that class pkg.D does not exist. If I try

```
 :prep-tasks [["javac" "pkg/D.java"] "compile" "javac"]
```

it can't find pkg/D.java, even though I set java-source-paths correctly.

One way to handle this would be to create 3 packages, one that contains A.java, one that contains b.clj and c.clj, and one that contains D.java. Then build a jar for D.java, a jar for b and c, that uses D.jar, and a jar for A that uses bc.jar and D.jar. Ugly, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have circular dependencies between the java and clojure sources in a single lein project. As you correctly point out, you could split the project in more than one package to avoid the circular dependency, but you don't need 3 packages but just 2, as lein supports [Clojure -> Java dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432163/java-and-clojure-with-leiningen). So you could have a project with b, c and D and another one with just A.

Another option would be just to write A in Clojure so you avoid the burden of multiple projects.

Comment: I pulled it apart into 3 packages. Once the dependencies are handled it's just as easy to make 3 instead of 2. A makefile is needed anyway. I didn't want to rewrite it as A is really the gui and D is the data. Thanks.