# How to import local Java class at Clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojure-java-interop

There are existing answers to similar questions, but they tend to use Maven, which is not an option for my project. Also, I have not found any which give concrete examples of the syntax you use to import at the repl, especially when the class is local as opposed to from the web.

I want to import a Java class into my Clojure project:

```
public class MyLocalClass1 {
    int x;
    String y;

    public MyLocalClass1() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = "hello there";
    }

    public MyLocalClass1(int x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

I successfully built it in Idea as Java2Import.jar.

Here is project.clj, where I import the jar:

```
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]]
  :resource-paths ["/path/to/my/Java/project/Java2Import/artifacts/Java2Import/"]
  :repl-options {:init-ns import-local-java-4.core})
```

However, when I try to import, I get errors:

```
import-local-java-4.core=> (import (Java2Import.Java2Import))
Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/import at (/tmp/form-init9909516591129619328.clj:1:1).
Java2Import.Java2Import - failed: #{(quote quote)} at: [:class :quoted-spec :quote] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/quotable-import-list
() - failed: Insufficient input at: [:package-list :spec :classes] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/package-list
Java2Import.Java2Import - failed: #{(quote quote)} at: [:package-list :quoted-spec :quote] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/quotable-import-list
(Java2Import.Java2Import) - failed: simple-symbol? at: [:class :spec] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/quotable-import-list
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Do you _want_ to build a jar with Idea and use with Leiningen (bad idea IMHO). Or would your rather build that java project, deploy a lib, use that lib with leiningen? Or use those java files directly inside from your clojure project?

Comment: I wanted to do the first option. What makes that a bad idea?

Comment: The proximate cause of your error is that you are using the wrong syntax for `import`.  Either use `(import packagename.classname)` or `(import (packagename classname))`.  You are using `(import (packagename.classname))` which results in the error you shared.

Comment: The bad idea is, that you now need intellij to build your project. Might be perfectly fine for one-person-throw-away-project. For any degree of reproducible build (share it with others, build in CI, ...) this is basically a no-go.

Comment: I wound up adding a directory in the src directory called java2import, and put the java files in there with package name java2import. (In other words I abandoned the local jar.) Seems to me that if java2import is its own git repo, and the Clj repo knows java2import is a sub-repo, that would solve the reproducible builds problem right?

Comment: @cfrick I took stuff from your comments and the answer and put them in https://github.com/jstr045329/import-local-java-4. Feedback welcome

Comment: I'd use a src/clj and a src/java directory to also keep the packate-to-directory structure for java correct. Or whatever is not confusing for your IDE.

Comment: It is crucial that you [set the :java-source-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11884604/1008794) value in your Leiningen `project.clj` file to point at the directory where you have your Java source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone this repo and look at the directory structure and also `project.clj`

- https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-java-template

The source code files look like so:

```sh
~/io-tupelo/clj-java-template > ls -1 **/*.{clj,java}
 project.clj
 src/clj/demo/core.clj
 src/java/demo/Calc.java
 test/clj/_bootstrap.clj
 test/clj/tst/demo/core.clj
```

The test namespace shows the correct syntax:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.string :as str])
  (:import [demo Calc]))

(dotest
  (is= 5 (add2 2 3))            ; from src/clj/demo/core.clj
  (is= 42 (Calc/add2 29 13))    ; from src/java/demo/Calc.java
  )
```

Run the unit tests in `test/clj/tst/demo/core.clj`:

```sh
~/io-tupelo/clj-java-template > lein clean ; lein test
Compiling 1 source files to /Users/alanthompson/io-tupelo/clj-java-template/target/default+test+test/class-files

lein test _bootstrap

-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 17.0.2
-----------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.core

Ran 2 tests containing 2 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

You don't need to compile the Java code into a JAR file. In face, it is much easier if you just use the Java source files.

You can also run in the REPL:

```
~/io-tupelo/clj-java-template > lein repl
Compiling 1 source files to /Users/alanthompson/io-tupelo/clj-java-template/target/default/class-files

demo.core=> (import '[demo Calc])
demo.Calc
demo.core=> (prn :result (Calc/add2 6 7))
:result 13
nil
```

Please note that the function call syntax of `require` and `import` **is different in the REPL** than the macro syntax of the `(ns ...)` form!

Also, any edits to your Java code will not be picked up in the REPL. You will need to exit and restart the REPL to force a Java recompile.

---

**P.S.**

As the README explains, I find it even better to use the `lein-test-refresh` plugin. IMHO it is like a REPL on steroids!

**P.P.S.**

If you only have a JAR file (i.e. not Java source code), you may wish to use the `lein install` command, which will copy the JAR file into the local Maven cache `~/.m2` where Leiningen can find it as normal.

Comment: Finally, a question where I agree your template project is a good thing to include in the answer!

Comment: I looked at your project and followed the directory structure to make my own. Any chance you could add the import statement in core.clj to show the correct syntax for a source file?

Comment: I took stuff from the answer and comments and put them together in https://github.com/jstr045329/import-local-java-4. Feedback welcome